# Windows Manager always overrides Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

So I Installed Windows 8.1 first and then Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop. Things were dandy until yesterday when I tried to boot ubuntu and it automatically went to windows. Tried to go through the bios and the UEFI boot file also "disappeared". Tried booting from a USB and the ubuntu options will come through. Any of the options will still boot windows.

What must happen?

Comment: This can be because of UEFI (secure boot) settings, please check it in BIOS setting and disable secure boot. You can refer this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work last time I dual-booted all I had to do was type in this code and follow terminal and the application

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair- saucy.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Type those in order and follow terminal and when boot repair launches click the first box and then follow what it says once done with that write down the command it says to type in. Shut down your computer and go to the system Bios and change the Os manager so it is first and find secure boot and turn it off if not already  boot into windows and then type in the command in a admin command prompt.